# Exploding gradient problem return NaN loss on CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a Convolutional Neural Network to predict audio data, which has as input a json that has been previously preprocessed in the correct way (there is no error here). However, when training the model, NaN values are obtained, stopping the training completely.

I'm working on google colab with Tensorflow 2.x. I try to reduce the learning rate, but was giving the same nan value.

---

**Model:**

```py
SAVED_MODEL_PATH = 'model.h5'
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
EPOCHS = 40
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_KEYWORDS = 10
PATIENCE = 5

def build_model(input_shape, learning_rate=0.0001):
    '''build CNN network: 3 layers, flatten the output, softmax classifier & model compilation'''
    # LAYER 1
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
                                  input_shape=input_shape, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.001)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

    # LAYER 2
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
                                  kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.001)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

    # LAYER 3
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu',
                                  kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.001)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    
    # FLATTEN INTO A DENSE LAYER
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))

    # SOFTMAX
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=NUM_KEYWORDS, activation='softmax'))

    # COMPILE
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

---

**Training:**

```py
def train_model(model, epochs, batch_size, X_train, Y_train, X_validation, Y_validation):
    earlystop_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="accuracy", min_delta=0.001, patience=5)
    history = model.fit(X_train,
                        Y_train,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        validation_data=(X_validation, Y_validation),
                        callbacks=[earlystop_callback])
      
    return history
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
Epoch 1/40
1166/1166 [==============================] - 5s 4ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0251 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0264
Epoch 2/40
1166/1166 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0251 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0264
Epoch 3/40
1166/1166 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0251 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0264
Epoch 4/40
1166/1166 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0251 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0264
Epoch 5/40
1166/1166 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0251 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0264
Epoch 6/40
1166/1166 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0251 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0264
365/365 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0261

Loss: nan
Accuracy: 0.026089942082762718
```

Comment: isn't your l2 regularizer too big?

Comment: @TheEngineer what size would you recommend?

Comment: Clip your gradients where you define your optimizer using clip_value or clip_norm

Comment: @talos1904 I already try to clip `opti = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, clipnorm=0.001)`

Comment: something like 4e-5. Also, why are you using sparse_categorical_cross_entropy? how are expecting your labels to be?

Comment: I'm using a lot of categories of preprocess [dataset audio](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/08/launching-speech-commands-dataset.html) using `librosa`.

Comment: the labels should be 0,1,2,3... which are define in the json file: `{"mapping": [], "labels": [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,...], "MFCCs": [], "files": []}`

Comment: I just tried setting to 4e-5. and I keep getting the same [here is the complete code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Aqmrog9L5R7WllFd5FaHAUqRN_y6kdC?usp=sharing) I'm pretty new working with this kind of dataset, any help or advice I will be greatful!

Comment: ok I will look into the code. meanwhile would you try using the regular categorical_cross_entropy as well?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, because my target is not one-hot encoding, instead are integers as I showed before.